# How do I pull data from an external database, and display it in Views?

Tags: views, 8, database

I am fairly new to Drupal, and just started working with Drupal 8. I know a table can be generated in Views for the content which is displayed/used somewhere on the site, and a table can also be generated as a "Content" with manual entries in there.

But I have a MySQL table - in a non-Drupal external database. I would like to use the data in that table, and generate a table on my Drupal site using that data, either as a View, or a Content,  or something else.

Are there any suggestions on how I can go about doing that?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Isn't your question actually "How can I pull data from an external database to be displayed in a View?" or something like that? Still quite broad though...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions to do this.

**First** one is to convert your data into nodes (content) and then easily show them in Views as a table. (You might achieve this using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. Export your table data as CSV and use Feeds to import it as a new content type.)

**Second** solution is to use the [Views Custom Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table) module.

> #### About
>
> View custom table module provide you functionality to integrate your
>   custom table data to views, and access all it's column in views. This
>   module use hook_view_data to add custom tables in views. this module
>   provides you following functionalities.